# Specifying both aria-label and title

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have an `input` for which I would like to provide an accessible label as well as a default tooltip.

Based on my research this is my understanding:

- `title` alone is not enough for accessibility.
- `aria-label` would not show tooltip
- specifying both `aria-label` and `title` might lead to some screenreaders reading both.

Is there a better approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, the best approach is to use a visible label with the `label` element, since this makes the input easier to use with voice control. (Voice control is why WCAG 2.1 introduced [SC 2.5.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#label-in-name): "For user interface components with labels that include text or images of text, the name contains the text that is presented visually." However, that SC does not require visible labels.)

If you don't want a visible label, you need to be aware about the precedence rules for "accessible name calculation". [WAI-ARIA 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#namecalculation) contains some basic information about this:

> name comes from values provided by the author in explicit markup features such as the [aria-label](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) attribute, the [aria-labelledby](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-labelledby) attribute, or the host language labeling mechanism, such as the `alt` or `title` attributes in HTML, with HTML title attribute having the lowest precedence for specifying a text alternative.

This means that you should expect a screen reader to read out the value of the `aria-label` attribute *instead of* (not *in addition to*) the value of the `title` attribute. A tooltip would just show the content of the `title` attribute, as expected (but screen readers don't use a mouse unless they have some residual vision).

Since the accessible name calculation algorithm in WAI-ARIA 1.1 is a bit short, the W3C is working on a more detailed algorithm in a draft specification that is currently available on GitHub. See [paragraph 5.1.1 in HTML Accessibility API Mappings 1.0](https://w3c.github.io/html-aam/#input-type-text-input-type-password-input-type-search-input-type-tel-input-type-email-input-type-url-and-textarea-element-accessible-name-computation)

However, the official specifications that are relevant to this question are currently WAI-ARIA 1.1 (cited above) and [Accessible Name and Description Computation 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#mapping_additional_nd) from December 2018.

Comment: "This means that you should expect a screen reader to read out the value of the aria-label attribute instead of (not in addition to) the value of the title attribute." OP is unfortunately right, if you provide both a title and an aria-label with different texts, some screenreaders will read the two (e.g. NVDA)

Comment: @VincentPassau That means the screen reader (or the specific combination of browser and screen reader) doesn't properly implement WAI-ARIA. Do you have any examples?

Comment: For this code, the screenreader tells "Firstname of your child - Edition - The firstname of your child" on Chrome 75.0.3770.100 with NVDA 2018.4.1  - <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
<input id="firstname" type="text" title="The firstname of your child" aria-label="Firstname of your child" />

Comment: @VincentPassau Thanks. NVDA + Chrome: that doesn't surprise me, since that was never the best NVDA + browser combination. See also [Screen Readers & Browsers! Which is the Best Combination for Accessibility Testing?](https://www.digitala11y.com/screen-readers-browsers-which-is-the-best-combination-for-accessibility-testing/) (2019) and [Pairing screen reader with web browser](https://www.perkinselearning.org/technology/posts/pairing-screen-reader-web-browser) (2017).

Comment: @ChristopheStrubbe Thank you for the references, that's interesting I'll take that into account for my future tests.

Comment: Last but not least, not providing a visual label is rendering the input **inaccessible to sighted touchscreen or keyboard users** and hard to use for other sighted users. Ironic, isn't it (:

Comment: @Andy Inaccesssible to keyboard users? There are plenty of search forms without a visible label that you can perfectly tab into. Try for example the search form at the top of StackOverflow.

Comment: Tabbing into it is not the issue, @ChristopheStrobbe. It's about knowing the purpose of the field. The search field on top still contains a search icon, and is quite alone.

Comment: @Andy Sighted keyboard users can usually determine the purpose of an unlabelled field from a visual cue (e.g. the looking glass icon used in search forms). (If they can't, the input field won't be usable to anyone, which would be a general usability issue instead of a WCAG conformance issue. Screen reader users can be helped with `aria-label`.